# Does injecting Bacillus F improve one's health?

Tags: biology, environmental-health, hygiene

In a Siberian times [report](http://siberiantimes.com/science/casestudy/features/f0159-russian-scientists-make-progress-on-secret-of-eternal-life),
a Russian scientist Anatoli Brouchkov claims that 3.5 million year old bacteria Bacillus F

- improves longevity and fertility of fruit flies and mice
- stimulated the growth and also strengthened the immune system in experiments with human blood cells
- allows 'mice grannies' to reproduce
- increases frost resistance of seeds
- enhances photosynthesis

In another [article](http://siberiantimes.com/science/casestudy/news/n0431-russian-scientist-admits-injecting-himself-with-35-million-year-old-eternal-life-bacteria/), the same scientist claims that he has injected himself these bacteria to improve his health which is also mentioned [here](https://www.inverse.com/article/6594-did-this-russian-scientist-actually-find-the-key-to-eternal-life-or-nah), [here](http://www.digitaltrends.com/cool-tech/russian-scientist-injects-ancient-bacteria-for-eternal-youth/) and [here](http://www.medicaldaily.com/eternal-life-russian-scientist-anatoli-brouchkov-injects-himself-35-million-year-old-354756).

Does injecting Bacillus F really improve one's health?

Comment: I see 5 questions in the body (all of which are actual claims in the article) and one in the title (which is not, in fact, claimed). Can we reduced this to a clear claim? Also, can we make the question factual? Asking "can x happen" is asking for speculation, it's better to ask "does x happen" instead.

Comment: I believe the edits by @pericles316 improved the question a lot, so that it better fits to guidelines now.